# Customizing a wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, themes, customization

I am trying to customize this wordpress theme : http://themes.industrialthemes.com/?theme=continuum

It have a slider named spotlight. It have a dark background. I want to change it. I right clicked on it and and selected inspect element. I opened the style editor and tried to modify the css to change it.

I checked the continuum/style.css. There it mentioned that, spotlight can be changed at component.css. I check there too but can not understand what to change and where. It is very difficult to find the exact place to change the code.

Can anyone please help me to go through the entire procedure of finding the right place to change the css code to change the spotlight background.

Thank you.

Comment: You can add your css code to the bottom of the style.css and then add !important to you rule. Like: .selector { rule:123 !important; }

Comment: If you use firefox browser you can use firebug addons. then you can easily identify the css class or id which need to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can see the elements and styles in Chrome developer tools (inspect element) then you should be able to adjust the style on the fly.  If you can see those changes happen on the site, you'll know you are in the right style place.

In top right corner of the style box you edited you will find the name and location of the style sheet.

In wordpress edit the template (having made a copy of it first of course) and specifically the style sheet you found above.  A template may have an odd style sheet or two so be sure you are editing the right one.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change background in class #spotlight. Here image is used,you can change it to color you want